# Check If A Service Account Has Logon Interactive Privileges

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I want to loop over all my domain service accounts and make sure that people can't log on the server using that account.

How can I check if a service account has interactive logon privileges and/or remote logon rights?

They aren't Managed Service Accounts because they are used as service accounts on multiple servers.

I tried `gpresult /s myservername /user myusername /h gpreport.html` but I don't really understand the report.

There was one section with:

```
Security Group Membership when Group Policy was applied

MYDOMAIN\Domain Users
Everyone
BUILTIN\Users
BUILTIN\Administrators
NT AUTHORITY\REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
```

Are these last 2 what allows this user to log in to the server?

Or is there a Group Policy I can check and look for using the command line?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a function of the user account, it's a function of the computer configuration AND the user account(s).

The easiest way to deny service accounts interactive logon privileges is with a GPO.

Open up group policy manager, and go to `Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment`.

Add your service accounts (or if you planned ahead, a security group, containing your service accounts) to the `Deny log on locally` and `Deny log on through Terminal Services` (or `Deny Log on through Remote Desktop Services`, depending on your Windows version) settings.

Apply this GPO to the computers you want it to apply to, and you're done.  (GPOs are still a rather large pain to deal with over a CLI, so I wouldn't advise that approach, but if you're deadset on doing it that way, that's what you'd look for, and where.)

Comment: This is a good answer. I'd like to try to get this via powershell to speed things up when checking multiple servers. However, I haven't managed yet.